# MigraDoc - Put TextFrame on Dynamically Generated Pages/Sections

Tags: migradoc

The red type paragraph generates multiple pages. Is it possible to put a TextFrame (that is not in a header or footer) to show up on each dynamically generated page/section in MigraDoc without putting it in a header or footer?

[image]

```
public static Document CreateWorkOrderPDF2(Document document, string filename, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;

        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 40;
        //Sets the height of the top margin
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 40;

        //HeaderFooter
        HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
        header.Format.Font.Size = 16;
        header.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;

        //Image
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image headerImage = header.AddImage("../../Fonts/castorgate.regular.png");
        headerImage.Width = "2cm";

        Paragraph headerParagraph = header.AddParagraph(WorkOrderHeader);
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";

         //Vertical Text
        TextFrame WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Orientation = TextOrientation.Downward;
        //moves text to the right
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Left = 550;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Width = 10;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Top = 0;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Height = 150;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        Paragraph WorkOrderVerticalParagraph = WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.AddParagraph();
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 8;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.AddText(WorkOrderHeader);
        //WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;


        //BODY PARAGRAPH
        Paragraph EstRecordsParagraph = section.AddParagraph(myMessage);
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkRed;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.RightIndent = 0;

        Paragraph renderDate = section.AddParagraph();
        renderDate = section.AddParagraph("Work Order Generated: ");
        renderDate.AddDateField();

        return document;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can add a TextFrame to the section; then it will appear once in that section.

You can add a TextFrame to a header or footer; then it will appear on every page where the header or footer appears. You can use absolute positions for textframes to have them anywhere on the page outside the header/footer areas.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but when I add the TextFrame to the header it loses it's "rotated" property, but I'm not sure why. Can you show me which changes to make to get it to work. I'm missing something.